# Xcode Test: Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 / Code=17: File Already Exists

Tags: xcode, testing, continuous-integration

When I run Xcode Tests, I get intermittent failures where the build freezes for 5 minutes or so on the `Touching App.app` stage, and then the fails with errors alluding to being unable to create the logs file because one already exists:

```
2023-03-13 10:43:47.473 xcodebuild[3695:44355]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Failure collecting logarchive: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“test-session-systemlogs-2023.03.13_10-41-40-+0000.logarchive” couldn’t be moved to “My Mac_CF8A13ED-B04E-49BF-AD2D-FFDF9B7679D9” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/tmp/test-session-systemlogs-2023.03.13_10-41-40-+0000.logarchive, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/folders/xq/sfn_fz953jb36ptp2g68wc2r0000gn/T/XCUITestOutput780702278/Test-Debug.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/My Mac_CF8A13ED-B04E-49BF-AD2D-FFDF9B7679D9/test-session-systemlogs-2023.03.13_10-41-40-+0000.logarchive, NSFilePath=/var/tmp/test-session-systemlogs-2023.03.13_10-41-40-+0000.logarchive, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001593180 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}
2023-03-13 10:43:47.476 xcodebuild[3695:16404] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 342.133 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2023-03-13 10:43:47.476 xcodebuild[3695:16404] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2023-03-13 10:43:47.476 xcodebuild[3695:16404] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 342.133 sec, +342.133 sec -- end
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the parallel testing option included by default in Xcode testing. Disabling the option under `Edit Scheme / Test Scheme / Tests / UITests / Options` fixed all my issues.[image]